# Como Escoger Grupo django cuando se registra

Tags: python, django, django-forms

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para escoger el grupo al que pertenecera el user cuando lo este creando, en este momento solo puedo crear usuarios pero no definir el grupo al que pertenecerá.

## VIEWS.PY

```
class RegistroUsuario(CreateView):
  model = User
  template_name = "registrar.html"
  form_class = forms.RegistrationForm
  succes_url = reverse_lazy('listausers')
```

## URLS.PY

```
path('users/crear/', viewsl.RegistroUsuario.as_view(), name='registrouser'),
```

## REGISTRAR.HTML

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
         <div class="card text-white p-5 bg-primary">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <h1 class="mb-4">Crear Usuario</h1>
                 <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                       <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Nombre Usuario</label>
                         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" name="username"> 
                         <label>Nombres</label>
                         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nombres" name="first_name">
                         <label>Apellidos</label>
                         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Apelidos" name="last_name">
                         <label>Email address</label>
                         <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
                         <label>Password</label>
                         <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password1"> 
                          <label> Confirma Password</label>
                         <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirma Password" name="password2">
                        </div> 
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Crear</button>                                 
                 </form>                    
             </div>             
         </div>
    </div>
```

## forms.py

```
 class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
    model = User 
    fields = [
    'username',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    ]
    labels = {
    'username': 'Nombre user',
    'first_name' : 'Nombres',
    'last_name' : 'apelidos',
    'email' : 'email',
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo he probado, pero si añades el campo "groups" que es el nombre de la relación M2M debería funcionar:

```
 class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
       model = User 
       fields = [
          'username',
          'first_name',
          'last_name',
          'email',
          'groups',
       ]
       labels = {
          'username': 'Nombre user',
          'first_name' : 'Nombres',
          'last_name' : 'apelidos',
          'email' : 'email',
       }
```

Si no, deberías hacer algo así:

```
 class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
     group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(),
                               required=True)
    class Meta:
       model = User 

       fields = [
          'username',
          'first_name',
          'last_name',
          'email',
          'group',
       ]
```

Y en la view

```
class RegistroUsuario(CreateView):
   model = User
   template_name = "registrar.html"
   form_class = forms.RegistrationForm
   succes_url = reverse_lazy('listausers')

   def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object.groups.clear()
    self.object.groups.add(form.cleaned_data['group'])
    return super(RegistroUsuario, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Gracias, quedo muy bien de la primer forma, sos un genio pero, pregunta, cuando estoy en la vista basada en clase, quiero listar los usuarios y mostrar el respectivo grupo alque pertenece, pero no me arroja ningun resultado